# A Problem regarding the Mean Value Property of functions .

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-measure, mean-value-theorem

**The Problem is**: If $x$ and $y$ are two distinct points in $\mathbb R^n$, then show that
$$\frac {Vol(B_R(x)\setminus B_R(y)) + Vol(B_R(y)\setminus B_R(x))}{B_R(x)}\underset{R\to \infty}{\to} 0$$

$\mathbf {My \  approach}:$ I was trying to apply mean value theorem taking the indicator functions $\chi_{B_R(x)\setminus B_R(y)}$ and $\chi_{B_R(y)\setminus B_R(x)}$ but I can't proceed any further.
Any hint is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would use the fact that $\int_{|z-x|\leq R} \,\mathrm d z = \int_{|w-x/R|\leq 1} \,\mathrm d w/R^d$, and so you would get things like $\mathrm{Vol}(B_1(x/R)\setminus B_1(y/R))$, where you can use that both $x/R$ and $y/R$ converge to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\omega_n := \operatorname{Vol}(B_1)$ and $x,y\in \mathbb R^n$. Making the change of coordinates $\tilde z= \frac{z-x}R$ gives that $$\operatorname{Vol}(B_R(x)\setminus B_R(y)) = \int_{B_R(x)\setminus B_R(y)}  \, dz = R^n \int_{B_1\setminus B_1((y-x)/R )}  \, d\tilde z. $$ Since $\operatorname{Vol}(B_R(x)) = \omega_n R^n$, it follows that \begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{Vol}(B_R(x)\setminus B_R(y))}{\operatorname{Vol}(B_R(x))} = \frac 1 {\omega_n} \int_{B_1\setminus B_1((y-x)/R )}  \, d z = \frac 1 {\omega_n} \int_{B_1} \chi_{_{B_1\setminus B_1((y-x)/R )}}(z)  \, d z
\end{align*} where $\chi_A$ denotes the characteristic function of a set $A\subset \mathbb R^n$. Then $$ \vert \chi_{_{B_1\setminus B_1((y-x)/R )}}(z) \vert \leqslant 1 \in L^1(B_1)  $$ and $$ \chi_{_{B_1\setminus B_1((y-x)/R )}}(z) \to 0 $$ pointwise as $R\to +\infty$, so, by the dominated convergence theorem, $$ \lim_{R\to +\infty} \frac{\operatorname{Vol}(B_R(x)\setminus B_R(y))}{\operatorname{Vol}(B_R(x))} =\frac 1 {\omega_n} \int_{B_1} \lim_{R\to+\infty} \chi_{_{B_1\setminus B_1((y-x)/R )}}(z)  \, d z= 0 $$ as required.